# Matlab find values greater than thereshold among column 5 of all matrices and replace with NaN

Tags: arrays, matlab, replace, find

I have an array of n matrices (45x5).

```
[45x5 double]
[45x5 double]
```

I would like to find all values greater than 1000 among column 5 of all matrices. 
Then I would like to replace these values with NaN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where all your matrices are in the 3D matrix `YourData` :

```
YourData(YourData(:,5,:)>1000)=NaN;
```

Comment: Thank you! What about if I have 2D matrix:

Comment: @user2387053 you have n matrices of 45X5 each. Combine them to one 3D matrix by `for i=1:n YourData(:,:,i)=matrixi end;` where "matrixi" is the i'th matrix

Comment: If you have _n_ 2D matrices of equal dimensions, it's much better using `cat` (_e.g_ `cat(3, A1, A2, A3)`) rather than a loop.